# Counting the multiplicity of weight of a Verma module without using the Kostant partition function or the Weyl character formula.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, verma-modules

For a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$, if $\mu \in \mathfrak{h}$ and $W_{\mu}$ is the associated Verma module, I want to see that the multiplicity of $\lambda$ is equal to the number of ways $\mu - \lambda$ can be written as a non-negative integer combination of positive roots. I know that there are various ways in literature to do it, some of which include the Kostant's partition function or the Weyl character formula. However, I would like to know if we can conclude the same without using these tools?

Comment: The number you want _is_ the Kostant partition function of $\mu-\lambda$, what do you mean by not using it?

Comment: I mean that is there any other way to count the multiplicity. Or the construction of Kostant's function is the only way?

Comment: Conceivably there are alternative formulas to describe the number of ways a weight can be written as a linear combination of positive roots with natural number coefficients, but that would still be a description of the Kostant partition function. What you are asking for is like asking for a proof of the prime number theorem without using the prime counting function.

Comment: You need to use whatever definition of the Verma module you have. For example, I have usually seen the Verma module with highest weight zero being defined as the negative part of the universal enveloping algebra, and using the PBW theorem together with the basis of negative roots for $\mathfrak{n}^-$ you can quickly see that the dimension of the $-\mu$ weight space must be the number of ways of writing $\mu$ as a sum of positive roots.